# How to Build Regex for this string

Tags: javascript, regex

This is my string

> hello my friend, i want to say hello to all of you

I am using following regex to match **hello to all of you**  But for some reason, it is matching entire string.

> hello(.*?)you

I think because I am using wild card match. I want start to be **hello** and end to be **you** and get anything between that, but not the entire string.

My regex completely ignoring inner **hello** word and giving me broad match.  I want it to be narrow.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! To improve your experience, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) an [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. You should also take a look at the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To lean more about how Stack Overflow works, [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: "I want start to be hello and end to be you and get anything between that" That is exactly what you got :P

Comment: If your criterion is "not from the start", you can use `(?<!^)` before your regex. It means "not preceded by the start of the string"

Comment: Criteria is not about start or end... i just want to narrow the match.  I do not want it to consider first hello word as there is already 2nd hello word after that.  Actual string is around 500-600 in words.

Comment: Then what is your criterion ? Why is the second hello ok but not the first ? What if there are plenty of other hello between them, which should be chosen and why ?

Comment: pick which is the closest before you word and ignore all others.  I hope it will make clear what i am looking for.

Comment: You could use negative lookaheads so that the inner text only matches anything that doesn't have "hello" in it, giving you this regex: `/hello(?:.(?!hello))*?you/` It works on your sample string, and I think it should work on all such strings.

Comment: @IceMetalPunk  Thank you only your solution worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is working correctly. Your string starts with `hello` and finishes with `you`. One way to prevent this is to restrict the character you want to match, for example your comma.  this way it will only match the last part of the string.

```
(hello(\w| )+you)
```

Here i'm only matching words, so the comma does not count.

You can try more case [here](https://regex101.com/r/k0Qhuk/1)

Comment: thanks, but this is just a demo string.    Actual string is around 500-600 in words, its having a lot of special characters and punctuation, so this logic will fail.  I just want to go for narrow match rather than broad match.  Since in given string there is already 2nd hello word, i do not want it to consider 1st one...

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: `.*(hello.+you).*` (js format with case insensitive: `var regex=/.*(hello.+you).*/i`)

Detailed here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/KzToql/3)

In the link I use g+m flag so it could match more, without it should only match the first line that have the occurrence, if you want to match multilines use `var regex=/.*(hello.+you).*/igm`, but idk what would happen to the group data selector when you do that tho, not an expert, just googling and try-and-error modifying the regex to find the answer for you lol, hope it helps.
p/s: Replace the center .+ with .* if you want allow next-to matching, ie: helloyou.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to get the last 'hello', until the last 'you', you can use

`.*(hello.*you)`

and your sentence will be in group 1 because of the greedy `.*`

Comment: This matches the whole test string and you have to fetch the group, I don't know what regex could match only the "hello.*you" part. If anyone can help on this theoretical problem I'm interested.

Comment: LogicalKip the regex I posted in a comment to the original question above will do it, using negative lookaheads: `/hello(?:.(?!hello))*you/`